# how to keep unique or most frequent value(s) per row for a pandas column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I Have a dataframe with a list of words and I was to keep the words  unique words if mentioned multiple times or keep all word if only mentioned once.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
cars 
[honda, toyota]
[honda, none, honda, toyota, toyota]
[lexus, mazda]
[honda, mazda, lexus, mazda, honda]
```

I want my out to be:

```
cars
honda, toyota
honda, none, toyota
lexus, mazda
honda, mazda, lexus
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does order within each list matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them into sets, a set inherently only has unique values.

Optionally, you can convert them back to lists again afterwards.

```
df.cars = df.cars.apply(set)#.apply(list)
```

Comment: That was very straight forward. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If order is important, use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) that acts like an ordered `set` (python ≥3.6):

```
df['cars'] = df['cars'].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))
```

Variant with a list comprehension that is potentially more efficient:

```
df['cars'] = [list(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in df['cars']]
```